# Android SQLite data inserting

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, insert

I am creating an android application that has two databases. One is offline SQLite database directly on the device and another one on public server that is used for update the offline one.

This is the way I'm inserting data into my SQLite database:

My activity:

```
package com.empekapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Linie extends Activity {
DBAdapter db
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.linie);
    openDB();
}
private void openDB(){
    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    db.insertLineRecord("1");
    db.insertLineRecord("2");
}
```

And in my database adapter:

```
public static final String KEY_LINE_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_LINE_NAME = "line_name";
public static final int COL_LINE_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_LINE_NAME = 1;

public static final String[] ALL_LINE_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_LINE_ROWID, KEY_LINE_NAME}; 
private static final String TABLE_LINE = "lines";

private static final String TABLE_LINE_CREATE = 
    "create table if not exists " + TABLE_LINE + "(" 
    + KEY_LINE_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
    + KEY_LINE_NAME + " VARCHAR not null unique);";

private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter (Context ctx){
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(TABLE_LINE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LINE);
    }
}

public DBAdapter open(){
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    DBHelper.close();
}   

public void insertLineRecord(String line_name){
    db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + TABLE_LINE + "('"
            + KEY_LINE_NAME + "') VALUES ('" 
            + line_name + "');");
}
```

Generally this solution is enough for me.. but data is inserted to the table everytime I'm opening that activity to prevent this I set the unique constraint but how to insert data only once, when I'm creating that table to avoid situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

use the data insertion in `onCreate` of database adapter class as this will be called only once when database created by this you can make it insert only once and no need to unique constaraint as well

Like this:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(TABLE_LINE_CREATE);
db.insertLineRecord("1");
    db.insertLineRecord("2");

    }
```

Comment: I guess this works, thanks a lot. I hope this will fix all my problems :)

Comment: I used exactly this part of code to make it work:

db.execSQL(TABLE_LINE_CREATE);
     db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_LINE + "('" + KEY_LINE_NAME + "') VALUES ('1');");
     db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_LINE + "('" + KEY_LINE_NAME + "') VALUES ('2');");